# PHP session variable not maintained after form submit

Tags: php, apache, session-variables, session-cookies, session-state

First off, I am new here and I don't know how to format my post nicely. Apologies. 
My script starts with

```
<?php 
 if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
 session_start();
 }
 ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_dir', "/tmp/");
?>
```

The form posts onto itself

```
form action = \"index.php\" method = \"POST\"
```

While debugging I noticed that after every postback, the session id changes and I understand that it should't.
There are no `session_destroy()` calls or other `session_start()` function calls in the script.
I'm unsure what additional information you need but I'm sure you'll let me know. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
Here is the session section of the php_info()

[image: sessionSettings]

Comment: Did you try removing the if around session_start?

Comment: check the session cookie settings. they may be too restrictive, causing you to "lose" the session on each request (http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php)

Comment: Is echo session_id(); and checking to make sure it stays the same after each postback a valid way to test this?

Answer (score 2):

try changing this:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
 session_start();
 }
```

into this:

```
 session_start();
```

Comment: That's how I had it before and I had the same problem.  I added the if statement on suggestion from somebody and it didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: then it might be something with your cookies settings in your php.ini, can you update your question with the relevant part of that file so that we can have a look there?

Comment: well i've compared it to the setup of the box i'm currently on and i see a few differences, these are my settings that differ from yours, so try to play around with those and see if it fixes your problem:

`session.gc_probability 1 1`
`session.save_handler file file`
`session.use_only_cookies off off`

let us know how it goes :)